# Selenium WebDriver Spicejet website automation?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate [spicejet.com](http://www.spicejet.com/) website, but the thing is I am not able to access the dropdown values using select as the dropdown values like destination, source etc are not in Select `Option="value"` format. When I try to work on using click and select the places it's not working as the click lands me in different page. and it's not only that, I have seen same pattern in many websites. using input field, buttons and lists instead of direct drop down lists.

Comment: Please show the exact HTML you are working with and also the code for the attempts you have made.  Then we can advise better

Comment: What client for webdriver do you use? python/java/js?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I have face this issue. Its really weird when all automation scripts and code written as per standards but ultimately it get failed. Below solution works for me:

**Step 1.**

```
WebElement listbox_webelement = drive.findElement(By.xpath("write_your_xpath_of_element"));
```

**Step2.**

```
listbox_webelement.click() [ Expected to list get visible ]
```

**Step3.**

```
Select select = new Select(listbox_webelement);
```

**Step4.**

```
select.sendKeys("Text_From_Your_Listbox");
              OR
```

**Step4.**

```
listbox_webelement.sendKeys("Text_From_Your_Listbox");
```

Comment: TrueAlpha - Your issue resolved or still facing it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Select class to manipulate an **ul** element (unordered list) and it will fail, as Select class was designed to cater select (i.e dropdowns) elements only.

Now to solve your problem statement, say I have to select Kochi(COK) from the list, follow the below steps :

1. Do a sendkeys.

   driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT")).sendKeys("COK");
2. Now perform a click using linktext.

   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Kochi (COK)")).click();

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact for drop down list, in Selenium we have Select class.
To use this select class you have to use import statement-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select
```

This Select class has several methods that are supported to access the elements.

- ByVisibleText
- ByIndex
- By.Id
- ByValue

Sample code:

```
Select dropDown1 = new Select(element1);            
dropDown1.selectByIndex(2);
```